# BDS 2006 webservice compatible with ws-i basic profile 1.0?

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, wsdl, delphi-2006

Are webservices written in BDS 2006 compatible with ws-i basic profile 1.0? 
Delphi seems to always add **use="encoded"** to **soap:body** which is against this part of the specification: http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.0-2004-04-16.html#refinement16448072.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this specific item, but if you're using Delphi 2006, [an update has been published](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/24535) for the WSDL Import and runtime that you could try.

Remember that you need to use the command line WSDLImp.exe instead of the one built in to the IDE.